# Package Variable is lost after being used as in script component

Tags: ssis

I have an execute sql task that stores the result set as a package variable with an object datatype. I have a foreach loop container that executes a data flow task. Inside my data flow task, I have a script component that acts as a data source. I populate the output buffer of the script component using the package variable mentioned earlier with the following code:

```
public override void CreateNewOutputRows()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    OleDbDataAdapter oleda = new OleDbDataAdapter();
    oleda.Fill(dt, this.Variables.ResultSet);

    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        Output0Buffer.AddRow();
        Output0Buffer.Column1 = Convert.ToInt64(row["Column1"].ToString());
        Output0Buffer.Column2 = Convert.ToInt64(row["Column2"].ToString());
    }
}
```

In the first iteration of the loop, it works fine. But on the succeeding iteration, the package variable value is lost. I'm not getting any record on my rows.

Comment: If you look at this example http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136060.aspx it looks like you need to move everything prior to the `foreach` into ` PreExecute()`... but Mike Honey is correct - why are performing this redundant step anyway?

Comment: ElectricLlama, I want to store the dataset in memory so that I don't have to read to the database for each loop

Comment: I also having this issue, i have a RecordSet as variable, it become NULL after used on script task.

Answer (score 4):

This issue is caused by populating the OleAdapter from your variable, see [here](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/26215469/SSIS-reuse-the-object-variable.html#answer32852989).

The way to solve your problem is, instead of populating a RecordSet, use ScriptComponent as a Destination, and populate a DataTable directly.

1: Create a Package Variable of type Object (E.g. LookupTable).

2: Add it to the ReadWriteVariables of a Script Component set up as a Destination, do this in place of populating a RecordSet

3: Add code similar to the below to populate a new DataTable:

```
public class ScriptMain : UserComponent
{
    //Create a new DataTable. This will end up getting passed around your package
    DataTable tbl = new DataTable();


public override void PreExecute()
    {
        base.PreExecute();

        //Set up the columns and PrimaryKey
        tbl.Columns.Add("Column1", typeof(int));
        tbl.Columns.Add("Column2", typeof(int));

        tbl.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { tbl.Columns["Column1"] };

    }
        public override void PostExecute()
    {
        base.PostExecute();

        //Populate the PackageVariable with the newly create DataTable object.
        Variables.LookupTable = tbl;
    }

    public override void LookupInput_ProcessInputRow(LookupInputBuffer Row)
    {
        //Now populate the table with rows from your query
        tbl.Rows.Add(Row.Column1, Row.Column1);
    }

}
```

4: Now in your future Script Components you can cast the variable straight to a data table:

```
var dataTable = (DataTable) Variables.LookupTable;
```

Now it won't get blown away each time you run the lookup in your script component, and you won't need to populate a DataTable each time, saving you precious time!

Hope this helps anyone in the future.

Answer (score -1):

I would remove the Execute SQL Task, and move it's SELECT statement into a OLE DB Source component within the existing Data Flow Task.  This would replace the Script component.  I would also remove the Package Variable as it would become redundant.

Comment: Mike, that would mean I have to retrieve from the OLE DB Source  for each loop which is what I'm trying to avoid. the reason why I want to store it in a package variable so that the data would be in memory already and I don't have to retrieve it repeatedly every time it loops.

Comment: Memory is cheap.  Programmer and tester time is not.

Comment: It's not about memory. It is also about the time it takes to retrieve the records for the data source over and over again during the iteration. But that's beside the point, I guess I'm missing the answer to the fundamental question: Why do you lose the value of a package variable, which in my understanding has a package scope, on the next iteration on a foreach loop container?

Comment: Your approach is so far outside normal usage of SSIS that I can't be sure, but possibly it's because you are trying to write output to the same variable that you are looping over?

Comment: The only thing that uses it is the Script Component and it was set to Read Only Variable

Comment: What approach would be more of the normal usage of SSIS for my situation? Going the OLEDB Source route proved to be taxing considering that I'm working with a very complex query

Comment: Perhaps this would be a good scenario for a Raw File then? Write it in an upstream Data Flow Task, then read it inside the loop.